# How to save data a user inputs into an edittext to be viewed in another activity within the same app

Tags: android, objective-c, database, eclipse, android-edittext

I am trying to save the data that has been entered by the user from an edittext field. To then be saved for later so that is can be accessed later in another activity within the same app.

I am basically asking the user to input `first`, `last name`, `phone number`, `email`, `address`.

I want to save that information so it can be viewed in another activity. I have another question regarding that activity but I want to stick to one thing at a time.

```
package com.internal.companyapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewCustomer extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_customer);
}

public void FirstName(View v)
{
    EditText firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
    firstname.getText().toString();

}
public void LastName(View v)
{
    EditText lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_last_name);
    lastname.getText().toString();
}
public void SaveCustomer(View v)
{
    Saveinfo(v);
    toast_newcus(v);
}
public void toast_newcus(View v)
{


    EditText firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
    EditText lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_last_name);
    Toast.makeText(this, firstname.getText() + " " + lastname.getText() + " is saved!" .toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
public void Saveinfo(View v)
{

}

}
```

When the info is entered the button is pressed the first and last name are brought into the toast to show that is has been saved. Of course its there for functionality.

How would I then save the data so I can recall it in the `viewcustomer` activity. I essentially want to be able to search for a customer then click on the name and have it take me to another activity that will allow me to just view the information.

Right now I want to focus on just saving the information then if I can't figure out how to recall the information I will post another question. I want to be able to save the information to a file that will be on the internal `sdcard`.

Comment: Do you actually need to save the data, or do you just need the other activity to know what data was selected (just need Activity2 to know first and last name or whatever data you're talking about)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for storing any primitive data.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the below article for SharedPreferences

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data until your application is active or your application not kill than you can also user [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
class of android. And generate getter and setter method there for storing and retrieving data.

Answer (score -1):

Define your variable "private static String" so it can save for till the app is running!!